# How Can I send AWS credentials with Python requests?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I've created the following resources on API Gateway:

```
https:/myapp.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zzz/yyy/xxx
```

It Can be only used it with AWS Credentials which I have:

```
access_key :"access_example"
secret_key:"secret_example"
session_token: "session_example"
```

I know how to use it with postman, but not with python requests. Can you help me?

[image]

I tried passing the credentials in headers, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

First, place your credentials into a correctly permissioned file at `~/.aws/credentials`, creating the `.aws` subdirectory in your homedir if necessary.  The syntax of this file is .ini style, with a section header, like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = AKIASOMETHING
aws_secret_access_key = shhhhhh
```

**You should not use requests directly.**  Use the official Python bindings for APIGateway, which provide high-level interfaces to AWS.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to sign HTTP requests basically add the authentication information to AWS request. AWS uses [SIG v4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html), you can implement this yourself or use existing python libraries such as:

https://github.com/jmenga/requests-aws-sign#signing-api-gateway-requests